# How to use the fwrite and fread in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a problem,

I keep a file in matlab, with the yuv format `int16` bit as follows:

```
nome_yuv = ( 'matriz.yuv');
% Filename = 'Imagem_Cube_Imaginario.yuv';
fid = fopen (nome_yuv, 'w');
elements = fwrite (fid, matriz16, 'int16');
fclose (fid);
```

Where the array is of type int16.

To read the same matrix I use;

```
fileID = fopen ('matriz.yuv');
x = fread (fileID, 'int16');
```

So my `x` should not be of type `int16`?

It is that my `x` is of type double.

Comment: If you got right answer, upvote the good ones and mark the most helpful as answered (tick mark below answer votes).

Answer (score 4):

If you specify two options in `fread`, the second option is interpreted as size of the array to be read.

See the definition in: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html

> ```
> A = fread(fileID,sizeA)
> A = fread(fileID,sizeA,precision)
> ```

That means, you'd have to specify all three parameters, `Inf` being the default value of `size`. So please use:

```
x = fread (fileID, Inf, 'int16=>int16');
```

Comment: Additional info from the docs: "Data in A is class double unless you specify a different class in the precision argument."

Comment: Thank you man, thank you so much, I use 'int16=>int16' in the fwrite too?

Thank you . Apreciate.

Comment: No need to, have a look in the docu: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html#input_argument_precision

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'int16=>int16' or '*int16', as by default output is double.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html#btp1twt-3